# The inferior stopped because it triggered an exception. Stopped in thread 0 by Exception...?

Tags: qt, debugging, visual-studio-2010

Complete Error Message in Debugger:

**"The inferior stopped because it triggered an exception. Stopped in thread 0 by Exception
0xfbdeba, code: 0xc0000005: read access violation at 0x0, flags= 0x0."**

I can compile my code without any error, but when I run it or debug, It crashes,

this error thrown when I used A QMessagebox to show a message, if I comment out this message program runs normally. I try to place QMessagebox in main.cpp just after Initializing of the QApplication the same error exist.

I can't understand what is the reason for this error???

Please guide me.
I use **QT 4.8.1 with msvc 2010 compiler.**

And what I try to do: I try to change an open source application named Open-sankore (source-code [here](http://dev.open-sankore.org/xwiki/bin/view/Community/SourceRepository)... ) and try to check that if user completed the registration form? if not show a messagebox to user.

I add a code part to UBApplication::exec(..)'s first line.

```
int UBApplication::exec(const QString& pFileToImport)
{

if(CheckLock() == -1)
{
   QMessageBox myBox;
   myBox.setText("Please Complete The Registration form to continue!");
   myBox.setWindowTitle("Warning!");
   myBox.exec();
}
```

After the error occurs debug cursur goes to UBBoardController.h and function below

```
UBBoardView* controlView()
    {
        **return mControlView;**
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that this error mostly happens when trying to use a variable that is not initialized.

Answer (score 1):

I have found one answer: this error occurs mostly happens when one pointer is not initialized. You should check UR code to find it. For example:

```
T* t;
t=NULL;
```

Just make the pointer a "NULL".

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the unused object is deleted in the destructor.

Answer (score 0):

**The same error was encountered with the reason "Smart Pointer was destroyed twice".**

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    ~A() {};   // doThing() must be called before the destructor

    void doThing()
    {
        m_edit->deleteLater();
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<XTextWidget> m_edit;
}
```

**Solution**: just delete the line `m_edit->deleteLater();`