# The inferior stopped because it triggered an exception. Stopped in thread 0 by Exception…?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging

I have a code to select a file, but when the dialog opens and if I do not select any file. The whole program crashes.
 Code:

```
void MainWindow::on_toolButton_Open_Advance_clicked()
{
    xmlpath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Open File"),MainWindow::getWorkingDirectory()+"/0_Config",tr("XML files (*.xml *)"));
    ui->lineEdit_7->setText(xmlpath);
}
```

I have defined `xmlpath` in the header `QString xmlpath` and initiated it in the constructor as `xmlpath = "";`

error:

```
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

when i debug:

[image]

EDIT: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497392/the-inferior-stopped-because-it-triggered-an-exception-stopped-in-thread-0-by-e?rq=1) I need to initiate the varibale, which i did.

EDIT2:

```js
void MainWindow::on_toolButton_Open_Advance_clicked()
{
    qDebug()<< "this is before:"+xmlpath;
    xmlpath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Open File"),MainWindow::getWorkingDirectory()+"/0_Config",tr("XML files (*.xml *)"));
    qDebug()<<"this is after:"+xmlpath;
    ui->lineEdit_7->setText(xmlpath);
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Process-crash with the message "RPC server is unavailable" on opening a save file dialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386856/process-crash-with-the-message-rpc-server-is-unavailable-on-opening-a-save-fil)

Comment: it's the duplicate of the [EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497392/the-inferior-stopped-because-it-triggered-an-exception-stopped-in-thread-0-by-e?rq=1) , but that doesn't solve my problem though

Comment: I don't think the code your supplying is sufficient to trigger the problem. Can you make a minimal example including everything from a Qt `main()` to your click handler?

Comment: @user5820174 It is not a duplicate of your link, error code does not match. Follow my link, try solution here and respond if it is unapplicable on does not work to prevent closing question as duplicate.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't seem to work for me though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getOpenFileName()` returns null string not NULL. Do this

```
qDebug()<< "this is before:"+xmlpath;
xmlpath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Open File"),MainWindow::getWorkingDirectory()+"/0_Config",tr("XML files (*.xml *)"));
qDebug()<<"this is after:"+xmlpath;
if (!xmlPath.isNull()) {
    ui->lineEdit_7->setText(xmlpath);
} else {
    qDebug() << "No file selected";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method 'getOpenFileName()' returns NULL in case the user does not select a file.

Therefore, check whether 'xmlpath' equals NULL before passing it to the successive statement.

Comment: "this is before: "
"this is after:" i think it's removing the NULL when I do not select the file, it has a NULL character before though. How do i keep the  NULL character even if i don't select a file. @kockie

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. What do you mean with "this is before" and "this is after"?

Comment: It was a debug command i put before and after, check the "EDIT2" for the code.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understood, but please keep in mind that an empty string and a NULL are 2 completely different things.