# Qt Creator and MSVC - Ignoring specific exception types on debugging?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, qt-creator, windbg

I'm currently using *Qt Creator 4.4.1* with *Qt 5.9.2* and the *MSVC 2015* 32/64 Bit compilers to create a DLL on Windows 7.

In Qt Creator under

**Projects** -> **Build & Run** -> **Desktop Qt 5.9.2 MSVC2015 *xx*bit** -> **Run** -> **Executable**

I've specified the host application, that loads my DLL, so when I hit **F5** this app gets executed and loads my DLL without a flaw.

However, on loading, the main app raises an exception which I have no hands-on, making Qt Creator showing up a message box with the following content:

**The inferior stopped because it triggered an exception.
Stopped in thread 0 by: Exception at 0x60251637, code 0xc0000005: write access violation at: 0x1, flags=0x0 (first chance).**

I now have to close the message box and hit **F5** again to proceed.

Because I have to do this for every test run, again and again, it becomes really annoying. So, is there a simplest way to tell CDB from Qt Creator to ignore **only that specific type** of exception?

Comment: Ignoring the exception is the worst thing you can do. For me, it sounds like something dies in start-up. (It could be a DLL failing to initialize.) I would dig deeper to find out what's going on, e.g. separate parts of your application and check whether exception persists, use Dependency Walker to get a clue what DLLs actually are pulled in, etc. May be, you can something isolate which you even do not need. May be, you didn't initialize something properly...

Comment: This is a similar question: [SO: The inferior stopped because it triggered an exception. Stopped in thread 0 by Exception…?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17497392/7478597) I found this and other by googling "The inferior stopped because it triggered an exception."

Comment: A general note: I hate errors which occur sporadically in release only. This might be caused by uninitialized POD variables. As VS writes in debug mode test bit patterns into any allocated memory (even on stack), there are actually no uninitialized variables in debug mode. Mostly, it helps but for certain things (e.g. `bool`s which are always `true` due to this) it's rather counter-productive. A reproducable error in debug mode (as described in your question) sounds like a lucky case in opposition to that.

Comment: "Loads my DLL without a flaw" and "access vilation" seems to contradict itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the call stack, find the relevant code and see what it does. You should find a `try ... catch ...` around that line. See whether you can avoid the exception in some way, typically by introducing an `if ... else ...`.

If you cannot avoid it, and you made sure it's really safe to ignore it, start CDB with command line argument `-c "sxn c0000005"` or the equivalent `-c "sxn av"`, where AV is short for "access violation". You can use `sx` to see all exception settings.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, the problem may be caused by the variable is not initialized, for example:

```
QLable *lable;
```

If you forget to allocate memory for this variable, it will cause this error.

```
lable = new QLable(this);
```

I think you should check your variables.